# Change IP address of azure app service

Tags: azure, dns, ip, cloudflare

I have an azure app service that runs through cloudflare. As the site was previously running without cloudflare you can find my sites IP address via DNS history here
https://securitytrails.com/

Knowing this it means an attacker could bypass my cloudflare DDOS protection.

How can I change the IP address of my azure app service without deleting it?

I'm guessing I could add a public IP and route all traffic from this IP to my existing IP, then I could firewall my existing IP to only accept traffic from the new one. This seems a little convoluted when I could just change the IP, update DNS during nighttime and accept the possibility of a few hours of downtime for users who like to work at 4am (none). Is it possible to force the IP to change?

Comment: Azure Web App service is a kind of PaaS,NOT IaaS. you cannot change its Public IP of the Service Plan. About the DDOS protection,Azure has DDOS protection for your service defaultly.See this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview

Comment: I didn't realise they had that. I like cloudflare as I can enable their "I'm under attack" mode in under a minute from my mobile phone. I find the azure interface much more clunky to navigate. But thank you for informing me of this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly it is not possible to change the IP address of an Azure App Service. What you can do is either delete the service and recreate it, or downgrade to the free/shared tier.

Both of these actions will relinquish your current IP. When it is recreated, upgraded you will get a new VM instance and a new set of IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: Scaling down to shared or free tier didn't change the IP for me. In fact, creating a whole new web app on a new app service plan still kept the same IP.  I didn't try deleting.

Comment: Not the answer anymore

Comment: Currently what i am facing is when app service stop and start i.e Auto sleep and awake on request then it changes its IP as-well.